# Query to fetch max date by values from a table ..my scenario is as below

Tags: sql-server

i have a table test as below

```
itemid revid    max_value
1        a      1000
1        a      2000
1        b      3000
2        a      9000
2        b      2000
3        c      7000
3        d      1000
3        e      2000
4        a      500
4        b      20000
5        a      12000
5        c      14000
```

Now i want to fetch the data as below .

Here i want the max(maxvalue) of each revid, itemid. Thanks.

o/p:-

```
itemid revid    maxvalue
1        b      3000
2        a      9000
3        c      7000
4        b      20000
5        c      14000
```

Comment: have u tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here i confused little about your current o/p. Your question says `i want the max(maxvalue) of each revid, itemid` But the O/P appears to be

```
select * from
(
    select *, 
           row_number() over (partition by itemid order by max_value desc) row_no 
    from table
) t 
where row_no = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this -

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM yourtableName a 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT itemid , MAX(max_value) mxy
    GROUP BY itemid 
)k ON k.mxy = a.maxvalue AND k.itemid = a.itemid
```